# python output not coming properly while being called from php

Tags: php, python

I have the following python code:

```
open_file=open("path to a file",'r')
from prettytable import PrettyTable
import csv
table1=PrettyTable(["COLUMN1","COLUMN2","COLUMN3"])
for lines in open_file:
    temp=(lines.split("%")[1])
    get_severity_no=temp.split(":")[0]
    Description=temp.split(":")[1]
    if "3" in get_severity_no:
        GET_DATE=lines.split(";")[0]
        table1.add_row([GET_DATE,get_severity_no,Description])
print(table1)
```

This code will simply print the desired output in a table format. Sample output shown below:[image]

Now I'm calling this script from php.
Here is the php code.

```
<?php

$mystring = system('python get_files.py');
echo $mystring
?>
```

Now this is the output that I'm getting.

[image]

All the formatting has been lost. Could u please let me know what I should do to make this proper? I'm very new to php but comfortable with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<pre>` tags around your output, as so:

```
<pre>
 <?php
  $mystring = system('python get_files.py');
  echo $mystring;
 ?>
</pre>
```

`pre` stands for "preformatted text", and pre tags render "plain text" **exactly** how it was entered, which is widely used for displaying code, command output, and other ASCII formatted tables & shapes (like yours) on webpages. Pre tags treat new-line's as `<br>`'s, conserves repetitive spaces (like you have in your table), treats < and > literally and not as HTML tags, and uses a fixed-width font.

You won't want to use `pre` tags all the time, because HTML tags inside of it, such as `<img>`, won't even be rendered. It displays any text ***literally*** as it was entered.

Hope this helps,

Comment: It helped. Thanks !!

Comment: What's a pre tag??

Comment: @soma It renders plain text in readable form, treating new-line's as <br>'s, conserves repetitive spaces (like you have in your table), treats `<` and `>` literally and not as HTML tags, and uses a fixed-width font.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference in how the console and the browsers actually format outputs.

The console represents new line with `\n` while browsers need proper HTML tags `<br>`.
Same thing for spaces. The console will print as many spaces as there are but browsers/HTML removes consecutive spaces (so that only one remains).

So if you want to have exactly the same output, you'll need to convert your line breaks from `\n` to `<br>` - you can use the `nl2br` function for that.
Regarding spaces, you'll probably want to convert all spaces to non-breakable spaces, to tell the browsers to render consecutive spaces. You can do that with a regex: `preg_replace('/ /', '&nbsp;', $str);`